# Plotly ticks customization

Tags: r, plotly, customization

I have try to find a solution in past post but unsuccessfully. I have simply to change the number of ticks on the y axixs of the following 3D surface plot (now with just 1 tick at 0)[image]

Using the following code

```
xn<-plot_ly(x=new$lg,y=new$va,z=effect)%>%
  add_surface()
xn<-xn%>%layout(scene=scene,yaxis = list(tickmode="array",tickvals =as.list(seq(-0.04,0.04,0.01)),ticktext=as.list(as.character(seq(-0.04,0.04,0.01)))))
xn<-xn%>%layout(title="Serratella ignita CTmax variation")
xn
```

Not sure what's wrong. Thanks for help